# How do you add strings to an array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I created a program that converts English words into pig Latin (part of my class). Currently it converts only one word: "hello"->"elloyay".

Out of my own curiosity I wanted to enable the possiblity reading multiple words separated by spaces and then have each one of these words converted accordingly.

More technically, use `substr` to grab a word between two sequential spaces. the input will be broken by `substr` to separated words. Each word in a time will be parsed by my `make_pig_latin` parser and will replace her corresponding word in that `string array`.

e.g.: the **input** *"hello yellow fellow"* will result in the **output** *"elloyay ellowyay ellowyay"*.

Can anyone let me know if my coding to accomplish this task is on the right track. I keep crashing in runtime and I think it is due to the array of strings not being created correctly. But I am not fully sure about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    string word;

    string word_List[] = { word };

    cout << "Enter your story (Please include spaces between each word): ";
    getline(cin, word);

    char c = word[0];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = i;
    int l = 0;
    while (i < (word.length() - 1))
    {
        if (word[i] = '\n')
        {
            string new_Word = word.substr(j, k);
            string test_Pig = make_Pig_Latin(new_Word);

            word_List[l] = test_Pig;
            l == l + 1;
            j == i + 1;
            i == k + 1;
        }
        if (word[i] = '.')
        {
            i = word.length() + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "The Story In Pig Latin Is " << word_List << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Extra information for the user to add: complete error line, compiler+version used, OS used.

Comment: Use a `std::vector`. `word_List` can only hold a single `string`, raw arrays have a fixed compile time size.

Comment: This kind of thing `if(word[i] = '.')` should be `if(word[i] == '.')`. And your array only has one slot.

Answer (score 2):

`if (word[i] = '\n')` will set `word[i]` to `'\n'`. You probably mean to test `if(word[i] == '\n')...`

However, you are getting input one line at the time, there is no new line in between.

You could instead break the text by testing for blank space `if(word[i] == ' ')...`

There happens to be an easier way. Use `std::stringstream` to extract words. Use `std::vector` to make array of string (or vector rather). Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string sentence = "How do you add strings to an array of strings";
    std::vector<std::string> vs;
    std::stringstream iss(sentence);

    std::string word;
    while (std::getline(iss, word, ' '))
        vs.push_back(word);

    for (auto wrd : vs)
        cout << wrd << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for that example. I am going to try it out, want to read up on vectors first to fully understand what they do, fairly new to this programming world. I will update if i can get it to work. thanks for your knowledge.